# Bitbucket to ColdFusion POST Hook

Tags: git, coldfusion, bitbucket, coldfusion-9

My company started using Bitbucket to host our Git repos and I haven't been able to find any good examples on how to properly setup a .cfm file for the POST hook to call and do an automatic fetch and checkout. The .cfm file is able to parse the payload but can't execute the commands. Any help or links to examples/guides would be much appreciated.

Server: Windows Server 2003 R2 with Git installed and running Adobe CF9 and IIS 7

**Code Sample:**

```
<cfset strRepositoryDirectory = "Z:\web\_repositories\someproject.git"> <!--- The full windows directory path to the GIT repository. --->
<cfset strExecutablePath = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i'>
<cfset strWebsiteRootDirectory = "Z:\web\someproject"> <!--- The full windows directory path to the website root. --->
<cfset strGitBinPath = "git"> <!--- The full windows directory path to the GIT bin folder. --->
<cfset strBranch = ""> <!--- The branch that was updated in the repository. --->

<cfset jsonPayload = "">

<cfset arrCommits = ArrayNew( 1 )>

<cfset boolUpdate = false> <!--- Flag that determines if script should update the website contents. --->

<!--- Parse the POST data and convert to a structure. --->
<cfif IsDefined( getHTTPRequestData().content )>
  <cfset jsonPayLoad = toString( getHTTPRequestData().content )>
  <cfset jsonPayLoad = ReplaceNoCase( jsonPayLoad, "payload=", "", "ALL" )>
  <cfset jsonPayLoad = URLDecode( jsonPayLoad )>
  <cfset jsonPayLoad = DeserializeJSON( jsonPayLoad )>

  <!--- Grab the commits, if any. --->
  <cfset arrCommits = StructFind( jsonPayLoad, "commits" )>

  <!--- Check the commits. --->
  <cfif ArrayLen( arrCommits ) EQ 0>
    <cfset boolUpdate = true>
  <cfelse>
    <cfloop array = "#arrCommits#" index = "idxCommit">
      <cfset strBranch = StructFind( idxCommit, "branch" )>

      <cfif UCase( strBranch ) EQ "DEVELOPMENT">
        <cfset boolUpdate = true>

        <cfbreak>
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
  </cfif>
</cfif>

<!--- Check to see if the website content should be updated. --->
<cfif boolUpdate>
  <cfexecute name = "#strExecutablePath#" arguments = 'cd "#strRepositoryDirectory#" && #strGitBinPath# fetch'></cfexecute>
  <cfexecute name = "#strExecutablePath#" arguments = 'cd "#strRepositoryDirectory#" && GIT_WORK_TREE="#strWebsiteRootDirectory#" #strGitBinPath# checkout -f'></cfexecute>

  <cffile action = "append" file = "#ExpandPath('.')#\deploy.log" output = "#DateFormat( NOW(), 'yyyy-mm-dd' )# #TimeFormat( NOW(), "long" )# -- Deployed branch: #strBranch# || Commit: Automatic PUSH from Bitbucket." addnewline = "yes">
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to set up a .bat file that you can run with `cfexecute` instead of making lots of individual `cfexecute` calls. You then need to be sure that the user assigned to the ColdFusion server is allowed to run that .bat file. I generally log onto the serve as the CF user and run the batch files directly through `cmd.exe` in order to ensure that everything is configured properly and I have the right permissions to execute everything that needs to run.